# why Acf & Pacf has different lags range

Tags: r, time-series, advanced-custom-fields, arima, pace

I'm working on time series analysis with ARIMA, and I plotted Acf and Pacf to specify AR , and MA values (p, q), however, when I plot them, the Pacf shows large lags like 10000, 40000, and 70000 even though I specify the lag.max= 20.

While in Acf plot, it shows the max.lag =20

Could anyone please explain why I've different lags range in my Pacf than my Acf?

[image]

[image]

here's simple of my data:

```
    Date_Time         Traffic_Flow
2017-07-17 02:00:00     -68
2017-07-17 03:00:00     128
2017-07-17 04:00:00     432
2017-07-17 05:00:00     802
2017-07-17 06:00:00     609
2017-07-17 07:00:00    -612
2017-07-17 08:00:00     -67
```

The data is in Time series format.
Here's is my code:

```
AcfData<- Acf(Data_Stationary, lag.max = 20)
AcfData
PacfData<- pacf(Data_Stationary, lag.max = 20)
PacfData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are using the `Acf()` function from the forecast package, and the `pacf()` function from the stats package. They use different scales to measure lags. Either use the `Pacf()` function from the forecast package, or the `acf()` function from the stats package to get consistent results.